# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in /usr/share/ocsinventory-reports

Tags: linux, debian, apache-http-server, php

It seems that since I upgraded my Debian server from Jessie to Buster ocsinventory  doesn't work and Apache send error logs like this one

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_init() in /usr/share/ocsinventory-reports
```

I think that I already have installed this library

> dpkg -l|grep -i curl

```
ii  curl                           7.64.0-4+deb10u1              amd64        command line tool for transferring data with URL syntax
ii  libcurl3-gnutls:amd64          7.64.0-4+deb10u1              amd64        easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (GnuTLS flavour)
ii  libcurl4:amd64                 7.64.0-4+deb10u1              amd64        easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (OpenSSL flavour)
rc  php5-curl                      5.6.40+dfsg-0+deb8u12         amd64        CURL module for php5
rc  php7.0-curl                    7.0.33-0+deb9u9               amd64        CURL module for PHP
ii  php7.3-curl                    7.3.19-1~deb10u1              amd64        CURL module for PHP
ii  python-pycurl                  7.43.0.2-0.1                  amd64        Python bindings to libcurl
ii  python3-pycurl                 7.43.0.2-0.1                  amd64        Python bindings to libcurl (Python 3)
```

I already removed curl restart the machine and Apache

If anyone could help me?

ThX